# JavaFx Greek Character Encoding

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, encoding, utf-8

I recently created an application in eclipse. I exported it as a runnable jar and with english all are working fine except greek letters. When i try to import a file with greek characters inside my application, they dont show properly. I tried changing all encoding to UTF-8 but no luck. I also have the exact application with greek menu and it doesnt show that correctly either. Only way to fix it so far is to create a runnable .bat file and paste this inside:

```
start cmd /k java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar Compiler.jar
```

But this doesnt make any sense to me, because every file and folder inside my project are using the UTF-8 encoding. I am using windows 10, latest eclipse and javafx for eclipse.

The greek letters exist in some files inside the project, for example src/grammars/xx-file. The application finds them and reads them without problem. Greek letters also show on Labels and titles of the applications. I use the default fonts of the javafx environment.
For example, one file contain this: I->#E|ε. When imported to the program it changes to this: I->#E|Ξµ

I also wanna add that in order to read those files from within the .jar i had to use InputStream. So it it possible to specify encoding to InputStream?

Comment: Where are the Greek letters? Source files, resource files or are you loading them from somewhere? Unless you specify a value for `-Dfile.encoding`, the platform default is used for file operations, so this is expected behavior in a normal Windows machine.

Comment: Does your java application have access to the font? Try running it from the command line (cmd/terminal) and see if it spits out an error, then update your question

Comment: No probelm from command line. As i said i run it with the specified code in my question and it runs just fine.

Comment: The problem is really unclear to me. Or is there a problem if you already solved it by specifying the file encoding in your deliverable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay for anyone insterested. I found the solution to the problem. I added an

`InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(streamIn, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

to every file that my application try to read, and by doing that it fixed the problem. So i guess the executable .jar file is not using by default the UTF-8 encoding and we have to specify it on the reading phase.

Comment: That would be the deterministic way to do it. Default is something the user controls and varies at will.